# Manually close database connections for AWS Aurora Serverless PostgresDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, database

Is there any way to manually close all open connections to an AWS Aurora Serverless Postgres database? Because the database is serverless, it is not possible to restart the database.

Comment: I can't recall if the root user has the right privileges, but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108876/kill-a-postgresql-session-connection perhaps?

Comment: Not the proper rights unfortunately. For this and some other reasons I've decided to refrain from serverless DB hosting altogether right now.

Comment: Do you have access to the user the connections are for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22713375/permissions-for-pg-terminate-backend-on-amazon-rds